# How to protect a buck DC-DC being backfed from the load (e.g. a battery as a load)?

Tags: buck, circuit-protection

## Background

I want to design a DC-DC adapter that is foolproof and has some protections in place so that it doesn't accidentally damage the somewhat expensive equipment downstream.

Here's what I have right now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCrY9F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input is variable, and doesn't need protection by itself. I've protected the [LTC3637](http://linear.com/LTC3637) against a few fault conditions. My biggest fear being that if it fails, and shorts the input to the output in the process, this might fry the equipment downstream. So far:

- I've protected the input of the LTC3637 against overvoltage;
- I have a TVS on the output just in case (this might also become a real crowbar circuit);
- I've made it impossible to backfeed the DCDC - if there's no input (SW1 open), and somebody connects a battery at the output, nothing happens;
- If somebody connects the same battery with reverse polarity, this would close the circuit around F1 and the TVS, tripping the polyfuse.

The load to the regulator is usually just the aforementioned equipment, but users might try to connect a battery as well, as this was required in the previous instantiation of this adapter and they may be unaware it is no longer needed. This prompted the scenarios in the last two bullet points, however I think the circuit would cope with them even without the D4 and the TVS, because of the buck topology itself, namely:

- positive backfeeding: If there were a wire instead of D4, the voltage from the battery would connect via the body diode of the power PMOS inside U2 to the input, so the regulator would be powered (Vin one diode drop below Vout). So it would be a strange condition, but not dangerous or damaging (and U1 doesn't care about backfeeding either);
- negative backfeeding: the battery would close around F1, L1 and D2, tripping F1 as before.

## Question

Are my worries about backfeeding well-founded, or is the buck topology is inherently protected against it (as suggested)?

Additional tips on how to make the circuit more resilient to faults and dumb users are *very* welcome.

Comment: If you remove D4 and input voltage drops below the output you could have high current flowing through the MOSFET in U2 that could blow it out.
If the battery is connected backward you would have a negative voltage on U2 SW that could damage U2 before the polyfuse opens.

Comment: @EE_socal: in the positive case, the current wouldn't be high (SW1 is opened). In the negative case, the voltage on the SW pin will be -Vf of D2. If D2 doesn't fail open before F1 opens... it's probably OK. There's no spec on what's the ratings of the SW pin tough.

Comment: Try Google-ing "flybuck converter" to provide complete isolation between input and output and staying with the buck topology.